# how to make a joint rotate a specified angle

Tags: gazebo, simulation, urdf, simulator-gazebo

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello,everyone! I am a novice in gazebo. I want to simulate my robot arm in gazebo. Here is part of my urdf file.

---

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<robot name="jixiebi">
    <link name="arm1">
        <visual>
            <geometry>
                <mesh filename="arm - arm1-1.STL"/>
            </geometry>
            <origin rpy="0 0 0" xyz="0.00039 -0.00037 0.0"/>
            <material name="arm1_color">
                <color rgba="0.752941 0.752941 0.752941 1"/>
            </material>
        </visual>
        <collision>
            <geometry>
                <mesh filename="arm - arm1-1.STL"/>
            </geometry>
            <origin rpy="0 0 0" xyz="0.00039 -0.00037 0.0"/>
        </collision>
        <inertial>
            <mass value="1.04075"/>
            <inertia ixx="0.004368" ixy="-0.00001" ixz="0.000002" iyy="0.004367" iyz="-0.000001" izz="0.002456"/>
            <origin rpy="0 0 0" xyz="0.000393 -0.000373 -0.074418"/>
        </inertial>
    </link>
    <joint name="arm1-arm2" type="continuous">
        <limit effort="1000.0" lower="-3.1415926" upper="3.1415926" velocity="0.5"/>
        <dynamics damping="0.0" friction="0.0"/>
        <parent link="arm1"/>
        <child link="arm2"/>
        <origin rpy="0 0 0" xyz="0 0 0.173"/>
        <axis xyz="0 0 1"/>
    </joint>
    <link name="arm2">
        <visual>
            <geometry>
                <mesh filename="arm - arm2-1.STL"/>
            </geometry>
            <origin rpy="0 0 0" xyz="0 0 0"/>
            <material name="arm2_color">
                <color rgba="0.752941 0.752941 0.752941 1"/>
            </material>
        </visual>
        <collision>
            <geometry>
                <mesh filename="arm - arm2-1.STL"/>
            </geometry>
            <origin rpy="0 0 0" xyz="0 0 0.0"/>
        </collision>
        <inertial>
            <mass value="1.26789"/>
            <inertia ixx="0.003947" ixy="-0.000001" ixz="-0.000617" iyy="0.006723" iyz="-0.000004" izz="0.005568"/>
            <origin rpy="0 0 0" xyz="-0.100667 0.000085 -0.013708"/>
        </inertial>
    </link>
    <joint name="arm2-arm3" type="continuous">
        <limit effort="1000.0" lower="-3.1415926" upper="3.1415926" velocity="0.5"/>
        <dynamics damping="0.0" friction="0.0"/>
        <parent link="arm2"/>
        <child link="arm3"/>
        <origin rpy="0 0 0" xyz="0.084 0 0.107"/>
        <axis xyz="1 0 0"/>
    </joint>
    <link name="arm3">
        <visual>
            <geometry>
                <mesh filename="arm - arm3-1.STL"/>
            </geometry>
            <origin rpy="0 0 0" xyz="0 0 0"/>
            <material name="arm3_color">
                <color rgba="0.752941 0.752941 0.752941 1"/>
            </material>
        </visual>
        <collision>
            <geometry>
                <mesh filename="arm - arm3-1.STL"/>
            </geometry>
            <origin rpy="0 0 0" xyz="0 0 0"/>
        </collision>
        <inertial>
            <mass value="0.65756"/>
            <inertia ixx="0.002035" ixy="-0.000006" ixz="-0.000239" iyy="0.002506" iyz="-0" izz="0.001401"/>
            <origin rpy="0 0 0" xyz="0.156093 0.000249 0.270754"/>
        </inertial>
    </link>
    <gazebo reference="arm1">
        <material>Gazebo/White</material>
        <turnGravityOff>false</turnGravityOff>
        <selfCollide>true</selfCollide>
    </gazebo>
    <gazebo reference="arm1-arm2">
        <stopKd value="1.0"/>
        <stopKp value="1000000.0"/>
        <fudgeFactor value="0.5"/>
    </gazebo>
    <gazebo reference="arm2">
        <material>Gazebo/White</material>
        <turnGravityOff>true</turnGravityOff>
        <selfCollide>true</selfCollide>
    </gazebo> 
    <gazebo reference="arm2-arm3">
        <stopKd value="1.0"/>
        <stopKp value="1000000.0"/>
        <fudgeFactor value="0.5"/>
    </gazebo>
    <gazebo reference="arm3">
        <material>Gazebo/White</material>
        <turnGravityOff>true</turnGravityOff>
        <selfCollide>true</selfCollide>
    </gazebo>  
</robot>
```

---

I have a c++ program that can calculate the value of the angle to rotate when you specify a goal position. So my question is how to make joints rotated a specified angle.
I have reviewed the gazebo [here](http://www.ros.org/wiki/gazebo) and I found there just offer a gazebo/apply_joint_effort.

---

When the model was loaded successfully,I executed the following command.

---

```
rosservice call gazebo/apply_joint_effort '{joint_name: arm1-arm2, effort: 0.01, start_time: 10000000000, duration: 1000000000}'
```

---

the arm2 rotate relative to the arm1 , but the arm3 also rotate relative to the arm2 and they kept running when I executed the following command.

---

```
rosservice call gazebo/clear_joint_forces '{joint_name: arm1-arm2}'
```

---

I went to know how to make the arm3 static relative to the arm2 when I just apply force to the joint arm1-arm2 and how to stop them.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/11113/how-to-make-a-joint-rotate-a-specified-angle/) by [shenhaobin](https://answers.ros.org/users/930/shenhaobin/) on ROS Answers with karma: 19 on 2011-09-04

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The URDF simply describes the kinematic and dynamic properties of your robot mechanism. If you want to make a joint rotate a specific angle, you need to write a controller that commands the joint to do something. The controller will probably monitor the joint position, and command joint efforts or velocities. See the [robot mechanism controllers](http://www.ros.org/wiki/robot_mechanism_controllers) wiki page for examples of controllers that run in the [pr2 controller infrastructure](http://www.ros.org/wiki/pr2_mechanism).

---

Originally posted by [Wim](https://answers.ros.org/users/38/wim/) with karma: 2915 on 2011-09-11

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

To expand on @Wim's answer, one example of using the pr2 controller infrastructure is here: [pr2_arm_gazebo](http://www.ros.org/wiki/pr2_arm_gazebo). It can easily be used on a non-PR2 arm, too. Here are the most important things you'll have to do (from `pr2_arm_gazebo`):

**URDF file:**

```
<gazebo>
  <controller:gazebo_ros_controller_manager name="gazebo_ros_controller_manager" plugin="libgazebo_ros_controller_manager.so">
    <alwaysOn>true</alwaysOn>
    <updateRate>1000.0</updateRate>
  </controller:gazebo_ros_controller_manager>
</gazebo>
```

Also, your URDF file needs [transmissions](http://www.ros.org/wiki/urdf/XML/Transmission) for each joint, otherwise the pr2_controller_manager won't work.

**Launch file:**

```
...

<!-- Default Controllers -->
<rosparam command="load" file="$(find pr2_controller_configuration_gazebo)/pr2_arm_controllers.yaml" />

<!-- Controller Manager -->
<include file="$(find pr2_controller_manager)/controller_manager.launch" />

<!-- Controllers that come up loaded -->
<node name="default_loaded_controllers_spawner"
      pkg="pr2_controller_manager" type="spawner" output="screen"
      args="--wait-for=/calibrated r_arm_controller" />

<!-- Fake calibration -->
<node pkg="rostopic" type="rostopic" name="fake_joint_calibration"
      args="pub /calibrated std_msgs/Bool true" />

...
```

**pr2_arm_controllers.yaml:**

```
 r_arm_controller:
   type: "robot_mechanism_controllers/JointTrajectoryActionController"
   joints:
     - r_shoulder_pan_joint
     - r_shoulder_lift_joint
     - r_upper_arm_roll_joint
     - r_elbow_flex_joint
     - r_forearm_roll_joint
     - r_wrist_flex_joint
     - r_wrist_roll_joint
   gains:
     r_shoulder_pan_joint: {p: 2400.0, d: 18.0, i: 800.0, i_clamp: 4.0}
     r_shoulder_lift_joint: {p: 1200.0, d: 10.0, i: 700.0, i_clamp: 4.0}
     r_upper_arm_roll_joint: {p: 1000.0, d: 6.0, i: 600.0, i_clamp: 4.0}
     r_elbow_flex_joint: {p: 700.0, d: 4.0, i: 450, i_clamp: 4.0}
     r_forearm_roll_joint: {p: 300.0, d: 6.0, i: 300, i_clamp: 2.0}
     r_wrist_flex_joint: {p: 300.0, d: 4.0, i: 300, i_clamp: 2.0}
     r_wrist_roll_joint: {p: 300.0, d: 4.0, i: 300, i_clamp: 2.0}
   joint_trajectory_action_node:
     joints:
       - r_shoulder_pan_joint
       - r_shoulder_lift_joint
       - r_upper_arm_roll_joint
       - r_elbow_flex_joint
       - r_forearm_roll_joint
       - r_wrist_flex_joint
       - r_wrist_roll_joint
     constraints:
       goal_time: 0.6
       r_shoulder_pan_joint:
         goal: 0.02
       r_shoulder_lift_joint:
         goal: 0.02
       r_upper_arm_roll_joint:
         goal: 0.02
       r_elbow_flex_joint:
         goal: 0.02
       r_forearm_roll_joint:
         goal: 0.02
       r_wrist_flex_joint:
         goal: 0.02
       r_wrist_roll_joint:
         goal: 0.02
```

Now you'll have to send trajectories to the arm and experiment to find the right PID parameters. (Hint: they'll probably be rather in the range of 0-10 if you use a transmission mechanical reduction of 1).

---

Originally posted by [Martin Günther](https://answers.ros.org/users/22/martin-g%C3%BCnther/) with karma: 11816 on 2011-09-11

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 4